# How to publish Outlook Anywhere 2007 using NTLM security with TMG 2010?

Tags: exchange-2007

I'm trying to publish my Exchange Server 2007 SP1 Outlook Anywhere feature through my TMG 2010 (Threat Management gateway), but how come I can only reach the stage where my Outlook client get prompted for credentials and can never login ?

I've made sure that the url in https is the same as my Activesync as well since we are already opening port 443 and SSL - SAN certificate already got:

activesync.domain.com

autodiscover.domain.com

Any help please ?

Thanks

Comment: you should give us the details of the OA rule.  Usually OA has it's own DNS name and own rule in addition to the autodiscover rule, activesync rule, and OWA rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing Outlook Anywhere Using NTLM Authentication With Forefront TMG or Forefront UAG

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=040b31a0-9a69-4278-9808-e52f08ffaee3